# C#-Selenium: Pass text to text boxes in the pop-up window

Tags: c#, selenium

Can somebody help me to find the text box identity so that I can pass texts to each of the text boxes in an opened pop-up window? I tried to find differences in each of the textboxes I found all have similar control types, I tried using "SearchProperties". I am quite new to Selenuim.

```
Code:
this.UserNameTextBox.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Edit";
this.UserNameTextBox.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "WindowsForms10.*"; // WindowsForms10.* is not it`s complete name, I dont want mention it`s complete name.
```

PS: I don't want to use "UITestControlCollection" functionality for some purpose.